# Framework Usage in C

Tags: c++, c, frameworks, ide

There are a lot of frameworks for C ,but most of them just give the frameworks file ,but don't explain how to link them to an IDE,what i did was include the header file of the frameworks ,but most of them had some more header file dependencies which i most of the times could not find anywhere in the framework ,I am a beginner and have no experience in framework usage.
It would help me a lot if someone explains me in steps how to link an IDE(Visual Studio,CodeBlocks or any other) to a framework.

I am searching for a unit testing tool based on Embedded C language(searching for a framework).I got many many frameworks like GOOGLE Test Framework,CUnit Framework,Embunit framework,AceUnit Framework and many more ,but couldn't find how to integrate with an IDE.

Comment: "How to use an arbitrary library in my project" is a broad topic. Pick a specific library that you want to use, try to add it to your project, then ask about specific problems you get with it.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, you want to do automated unit-tests when building a project? If that's the case it essentially boils down to "how to execute an application as a pre- or post-build step", which heavily depends on the IDE you are using.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your post and title talk about the C language, yet you tagged C++.  They are distinct languages.  Are you mixing languages?  I recommend not mixing them and staying with one language.  Please update your tags appropriately.  An example difference:  C++ has inheritance, such as `class Button` can inherit from `class Window`.  C doesn't have inheritance; you'll have to emulate it (can be very messy).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How about you read the question instead of copy pasting a standard "C is not C++" response. It is perfectly acceptable to use a C++ unit test framework for C code. Besides, the toolchain used for building C and C++ projects is almost identical in most cases.

Comment: @para I read the question.  Can you tell me where the OP mentions the C++ language?  If this is a recommendation request, it doesn't belong on StackOverflow.  Like I said, there are differences.  A lot of frameworks are in C++ because of the inheritance capabilities.  However, I have programmed and seen frameworks that use C language.  Also, there are a lot of IDE & GUI framework combos that don't work.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He mentioned Google Test Framework which generates C++ code and Embunit which can also generate C++ code.